# Plot geometry of longitude and latitude coordinates using javascript

Tags: javascript, plot, geometry, coordinates, latitude-longitude

I have longitude and latitude coordinates which represent different types of geometry shapes (point, multi-point, polygon, multi-polygon and line string etc) that are stored in MongoDB. I'd like plot them (say each shape as a layer) using JavaScript. Map is not needed as a background although these coordinates represent building etc in the real world. I understand there are calculations as such are involved to convert coordinates to x and y on graph/canvas but not sure where to begin tbh. I'm very new to GIS and JavaScript so go easy on me please. I know this question sounds a bit vague but bottom line is I have coordinates that represent real world elements and want to plot them without a map background. I'd appreciate advises and suggestions. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do it is to use a Javascript mapping library such as OpenLayers or Leaflet. You could also do it with D3, although should you want to make your map more full-featured later, it will be much easier with a library that was designed for that type of thing.

If you are storing your data in Mongo as [GeoJSON](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/geospatial-queries/) ([GeoJSON website](http://geojson.org/)), you can add it to OpenLayers as a [GeoJSON layer](http://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/geojson.html).

Disclaimer- My opinions might be slightly biased because I used to work for Boundless

Comment: Thank you @onwsk8r Should have mentioned that the coordinates are stored as GeoJson loc and have indexed. I understand the point of using the mapping library. However, due to the details info I have on the coordinates I rather not use a background map. Would it not be possible? On the other hand, you have a very good point for future. Thanks for pointing that out

Comment: @Max you don't have to use a basemap if you don't want to. Openlayers just provides the functionality; if you don't specify a base layer, you won't have a basemap.

Comment: thanks a lot for getting back. I didn't know that. I found a library called D3. It looks promising too. I am getting to know it for now.

Comment: D3 is really great (I use it for several things) although you're going to have to write a lot more code in order to make it work, whereas with OL you only need about 10 LOC, which can be stolen directly from the geojson example on their website. In fact you could copy it directly and replace the geojson with your GeoJSON and have something to show. However D3 is also really in demand, so learning it well could probably land you a job.

Comment: thanks a lot man. The main reason I chose d3 was because it's rich in functionality. I will need that for this project. Please do have a look at [link] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51731404/plot-polygon-using-d3) if you have time. Thanks so much mate