# Plot polygon using D3

Tags: javascript, d3.js, polygon, geojson

I am trying to plot a polygon using a .json file.

*EDIT to add sample coordinates

```
{  "type": "FeatureCollection",  "features": [    {
  "type": "Feature",
  "geometry": {
                "type": "Polygon",
        "coordinates": [
            [
                [
                    -0.0691250297447329,
                    51.5462448874379
                ],
                [
                    -0.0691510961928943,
                    51.5459630404703
                ],
                [
                    -0.0692056531364391,
                    51.5456827414947
                ],
                [
                    -0.0692883661627076,
                    51.5454050640766
                ],
                [
                    -0.0693070134960316,
                    51.545356361588
                ],.....
```

The script looks like

```
var width = 960;
    var height = 600;

    var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
        .attr("width", width)
        .attr("height", height);


    d3.json("/GeoJsonFiles/samplePolygon1.json", function (error, json) {
        if (error) console.error(error);

        var projection = d3.geoMercator()
            .fitSize([width, height], json);
        var path = d3.geoPath().projection(projection);
        svg.selectAll("path")
            .data(json.features)
            .enter()
            .append("path")
            .attr("d", path)
            .attr("fill", "gray")
            .attr("stroke", "black");});
```

As far as I can tell there is no error but svg doesn't display a thing. I have also tried methods like `scale()` `center()`and `offset()`. Nothing works so far. This is my first D3 script - do help.

Comment: What do your coordinates look like? Sharing a few in  your example geojson would be beneficial. Also have you validated the geojson?

Comment: Hello Andrew! Thanks for your comment. Please see the update for sample coordinates. I used [link] (https://npm.runkit.com/geojson-validation) which uses  `geojson-validation` to validate the coordinates. They are correct. Any thoughts please?

Comment: Complete coordinates for the polygon can be found on [link] (https://api.myjson.com/bins/vfga0)

Comment: @Max What version of D3 do you use?

Comment: @altocumulus it's v4. I fond out that d3.js uses right hand rule/coordinates in clockwise so checked to make sure the polygon is clockwise. Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

Found this [D3 polygon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13204562/proper-format-for-drawing-polygon-data-in-d3?answertab=votes#tab-top)
Turns out the following code was essential.

```
.attr("points", function (d) {
  return d.map;
})
```

The complete code is as follows.

```
d3.json("/GeoJsonFiles/samplePolygon1.json", function (error, json) {
                if (error) console.error(error);

                var projection = d3.geoMercator()
                    .fitSize([width, height], json);
                var path = d3.geoPath().projection(projection);
                svg.selectAll("path")
                    .data([json])
                    .enter()
                    .append("path")
                    .attr("points", function (d) {
                        return d.map;
                    })
                    .attr("d", path)
                    .attr("fill", "gray")
                    .attr("stroke", "black");
            });
```

Comment: Shouldn't need d3.polygon, especially as `path` doesn't reference a `points` attribute. I had no difficulty in displaying your geojson with just a projection and path: https://bl.ocks.org/Andrew-Reid/19d88c2ff1dba0fa0f1963babbf1bf9c . Perhaps there was an odd issue with the feature collection (rather than the individual feature shared).

Comment: Thank you Andrew. That's strange. I tried that didn't have any error but a blank SVG. Just tried it again to make sure. It's the same. You might be right about the feature collection though.

Comment: D3's geojson validation is relatively strict and as far as I'm aware doesn't throw errors, which could explain the behavior you are seeing. One option would be to log `path(featureCollection)` and see if anything returned looks like path data.

Comment: Your explanation makes sense. Thank you. Unfortunately, I was unable to log it as console keeps saying `Uncaught ReferenceError: path is not defined` Although you can see I'm using path to draw. I really can't get my head around